# Qt execute multiple get with QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: c++, qt, c++17

I have to execute a lot of get requests and they have to be hadled in different ways. So far, I have this simply approach that works:

[image]

And here's the code for `.h`:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();

    void finish(QNetworkReply *reply);

    void finish2(QNetworkReply *reply);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QNetworkAccessManager* manager;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

And code for `.cpp`:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);    
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

//First request here...
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this, &MainWindow::finish);

    manager->get(QNetworkRequest{QUrl{"http://www.link.com/path/"}});
}

//... is completed here
void MainWindow::finish(QNetworkReply *reply) {
    if (reply->error()) {
        ui->lineEdit->setText("error");
        qDebug() << reply->errorString();
    } else {
            ui->lineEdit->setText(QString{reply->readAll()});
    }
}

//Second request here...
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this, &MainWindow::finish2);

    manager->get(QNetworkRequest{QUrl{"https://ergast.com/api/f1/2008/5.json"}});
    qDebug() << "chiamata";
}

//... is completed here
void MainWindow::finish2(QNetworkReply *reply) {
    if (reply->error()) {
        ui->lineEdit_2->setText("error");
        qDebug() << reply->errorString();
    } else {
            ui->lineEdit_2->setText(QString{reply->readAll()});
    }
}
```

---

When I press both buttons the requests happen but my UI blocks. I have tried this approach because I have seen in many examples that it's good to have a `QNetworkAccessManager* manager;` as private field and re-use it.

It does not seem by the way the best approach. Is there a proper way to do multiple calls?

Should I declare maybe an array of `QNetworkAccessManager*` and execute there all the calls?

---

I have also seen that there's the possibility to create a private field called `QNetworkReply* reply;` and then use it like this:

```
manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);  
reply = manager->get(QNetworkRequest{QUrl{"http://www.link.com/path/"}});
connect(manager, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, &MainWindow::finish);
```

I think that this is equivalent to the method I am using but in this case I don't know how to handle multiple requests because I am bind to the `finish` method and I should implement all the logic there.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested your code and I have not noticed that the GUI is blocked, in addition to using signals and slots you should not have that problem. However I see that you are creating dynamic memory unnecessarily, in the following code I connect the `QNetworkReply` to a slot, filter through the `QUrl` and delete the `QNetworkReply`:

***.h**

```
...
private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();
    void onReplyfinished();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager;
...
```

***.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
   QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(QNetworkRequest{QUrl{"http://www.link.com/path/"}});
   connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, &MainWindow::onReplyfinished);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
   QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(QNetworkRequest{QUrl{"https://ergast.com/api/f1/2008/5.json"}});
   connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, &MainWindow::onReplyfinished);
}

void MainWindow::onReplyfinished()
{
    QNetworkReply *reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply*>(sender());
    if(reply->url() == QUrl{"http://www.link.com/path/"}){
        ui->lineEdit->setText(reply->error() ? "error": reply->readAll());
    }
    else if (reply->url() == QUrl{"https://ergast.com/api/f1/2008/5.json"}){
        ui->lineEdit_2->setText(reply->error() ? "error": reply->readAll());
    }
    reply->deleteLater();
}
```

Comment: Instead of checking for the URL in the slot, I'd rather connect to two different slots handling the respective responses.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Everyone has their opinion, if you do not indicate an objective reason for your choice, we can not discuss the advantages or disadvantages. :-)

Comment: You'd avoid duplicating the URL in two places, so it's more robust when you happen to change the URL in the request. Also, the slots become simpler and their purpose more explicit.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I would apply what you want if there are only 2 urls, my answer goes in the case of n urls, then I could associate a QUrl to a QModelIndex so I could use a QListView to show the results, it depends on the application.